# Why is my Overrides Function not overriding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

VS2103, MVC5, VB

**What I'm tyring to do:** Keep the templated MVC5 Controller and Model .vb files without changes to the code 'inside' the templated methods and keep all the method changes in a separate file.

This post is edited in response to the initial 4 comments below:

To replicate what I'm seeing start a new MVC5 project.  Then edit the HomeController.vb file as below, simply adding Overridable to the Function Index.

```
Public Class HomeController
Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

  Overridable Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View()
  End Function

  Function About() As ActionResult
    ViewData("Message") = "Your application description page."

    Return View()
  End Function

  Function Contact() As ActionResult
    ViewData("Message") = "Your contact page."

    Return View()
  End Function
End Class
```

Then add a file named HomeControllerOverrides.vb that looks as follows:

```
Public Class OverridesToHomeController
  Inherits HomeController

  Overrides Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View()
  End Function

End Class
```

You'll have to create a View for the Index method in this second file.

When you run the program, the Overrides Function does not get executed, only the original Function.

Best Regards,
Alan

Comment: Is it possible that your object isn't a `HomeControllerOverrides` but actually a `HomeController`?  That's only explanation I can come up with.  We'd need to see the code where your object is created and called.

Comment: Try to rename HomeController -> HomeControllerBase and HomeControllerOverrides -> HomeController. The controller being called depends on how the page was setup.

Comment: What you're trying to do is, in my opinion, rather misguided.  What exactly do you think you gain by doing such a thing?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the name of a controller has to end with "Controller".  MVC uses convention over configuration in many cases and that is one of the conventions.  Look at your routes.  How exactly are you specifying that that is to be used when someone navigates to the "Home/Index" URL?

Comment: @j.i.h Thanks for the look.  I changed the post to use only the MVC5 template in an effort to make sure everything I'm doing is able to be seen.  Does that work?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Good point about the convention; I changed that as you can see, but unfortunately it didn't fix the issue.  Re why, I was pretty sure some might not see this of value, but for me as one new to the template, I wanted to keep the changes I'm making separate so it's easier to see what was my coding versus what came in the template, that's all.  It also helps if I want to transport code or models to a different project by quickly starting a template and adding my files.  I'm sure there are easier ways, this is just the one I came up with, and then I hit this oddity.

Comment: @the_lotus I worked on your suggestion last, and that worked.  I will post the answer in a post below per your recommendations, but I'd like to understand why this worked.  What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your global.asax, there should be a section that maps url to controllers

```
    routes.MapRoute( _
        "MainPage", _
        "", _
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index"} _
    )
```

or

```
    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Default", _
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )
```

If you have the default controller. It'll use the first folder name as the controller name or use Home as default. You'll need to rename HomeController -> HomeControllerBase and HomeControllerOverrides -> HomeController. The controller being called depends on how the page was setup.

Depending on how it's setup, you could've done http://website.com/OverridesToHome to acces your new class.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  It seems the issue was I tried my first naming methods on the one Controller impacted by the default, as you show above.  I liked your suggestion for naming and will use that, but I'll go back and check on a Controller that is not the default with the way I was doing it at first just to confirm for myself that would work on Controllers other than Home.  Thx!